# Examples when white box testing fails but black box test is successful and vice versa?

Tags: testing

Can you give me certain examples in which black box testing gives the impression that "everything is ok" but white box testing might uncover an error. And examples where white box testing gives an impression that "everything is ok" but black box testing might uncover an error??

Thanx in advance

Comment: Nice question. Something that I want as of now. Can anyone can help out with even more good answers?

Answer (score 2):

Blackbox testing *can* miss pretty much anything that isn't clearly documented or intuitive. For example, in this SO answer entry section, I have a toolbar that I can "test", but w/o taking a look at the code, I may not discover that I need to test the hotkeys, or understand how highlighted text responds to bold and italic attributes in random combinations. I can experiment and figure this out, but it's not as efficient.

In larger applications, control flow issues are often missed - think of obscure logic flows, or even rareley executed case statements.

However, if you do white box testing only, usability is typically the first to suffer. A perfectly functional piece of software can also be difficult to use, have unaligned UI elements, etc.

Why do you ask?

Comment: @Alan : Can you provide us with even more elaborate answer? Maybe a test case study?

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across it while studying for exam wish me luck.
Lets suppose you being a programmer keeping a track of users logging into your website or whatever, and the counter you have kept is of type int, the range of int is as you know 65,535 and your number of users exceeds the range of the type. in that case black box test might be unable to detect what's going on in between, but white box test will do.

Answer (score 1):

For specific input, an error occurs internally resulting in:

1. Improper data placed in a global data area;
2. Improper flags that will be tested in a subsequent series of tests;
3. Improper hardware control that can only be uncovered during system test; yet "correct" output is produced.

Error detection by white-box testing contradicting black-box testing:

- Testing to ensure that all independent paths within a module will be executed at least once.
- Testing to exercise all logical decisions on their true and false branches.
- Testing to ensure that all loops execute at their boundaries and within their operational bounds.

Error detection by black-box testing contradicting white-box testing:

- Testing for interface functionality.
- Testing system behavior and performance.
- Test for classes of input.